# How do I disable win-31 theme on Stackoverflow?

Tags: themes

How do I disable it? Or should I wait for 24h timer?
I tried to search for a setting but could not find it.

If anyone can help me that would be awesome. I prefer pastel.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom right corner you should see a button named "Filters". Click this button and you can see various filters popping up. You can choose one of them or use the default theme.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: It's gone now :D